# Hash values in Ruby stored as copies?

Tags: ruby, hash

When I run what's below, I get

```
false
false
```

as output. I would expect this instead:

```
false
true
true
```

The code:

```
a = Object.new
b = Object.new

my_hash = {}
my_hash['one'] = [a, b]
my_hash['two'] = [b]

my_hash.each do |key, value|
  puts value == b
end
```

It doesn't seem objects referenced in "value" in the iterator are the same objects as "a" and "b." Why?

Answer (score 3):

The code is comparing an array (hash value) with the object `b`.

You should compare each item of array to get the expected result:

```
a = Object.new
b = Object.new

my_hash = {}
my_hash['one'] = [a, b]
my_hash['two'] = [b]

my_hash.each do |key, array|
  array.each do |item| # <---
    puts item == b
  end                 # <---
end
```

outupt:

```
false
true
true
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `each` on the hash doesn't iterate over the arrays that are the values.

So `my_hash.each` is effectively running:

```
 [a, b] == b #=> false
 [b] == b #=> false
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-each